# How to protect the function of unpredictable behavior after change of optimization level of compiler (C programming)?

Tags: c

I have a lot of problems related with optimization level of GCC compiler. Sometimes behavior of my C routines are dramatically changed when set the compilation level to higher, and they do not work as expected. GCC compiler is a part of Atollic TrueStudio IDE.

Does anyone can give me advice on this topic? What is the universal approach in solution of this kind of problem?

My apologize if I'm not 100% precise.

Comment: Could you post an example? Optimization should and will not change the behaviour of your code if you are writing portable code. The only time that happens is if there is a bug in the GCC optimizer or you are writing non-standard C code.

Comment: Set warnings to maximum read them and use printf if you cannot debug. Your code has probably problems like uninitialized vars...

Comment: Either there's a bug in your code, or there's a bug in the optimizer. Post your code, so that we can determine which of the two it is.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (too short to be an answer)

Comment: Note that if you have *undefined behaviour* (as defined in C standard), then you may get nasty suprises even with unoptimized builds. Pay special attention to type casts as they hide compiler warnings.

Answer (score 7):

Write better code. Correct code will not change behavior with different optimization levels.

Avoid:

- Undefined behavior. This shouldn't need mentioning, but it's really important since GCC is often using the assumption "code doesn't trigger UD" to drive optimizations.
- Implementation-specified behavior. These might change with different optimization flags. Perhaps not too common, but I think it can happen.

Use compiler warnings, linters and other static analysis tools to help you find errors in your code (or, of course, debug the problems you see when you turn on optimization).